# Do anyone know how to import data in a cell already filled with other data (financial statement from different stocks sharing same cells)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have tried to automate my spreadsheet with imported data, in this case financial statements (balance sheet, income statement, cashflow statement) in google sheet.
I have been able to get tickers data one by one but I could not make it automatic like for a stock (company) price.
The problem is that data can not be imported automatically beecause cells were already filled with data from the first company.

My question is: do anyone know how I can overcome this google sheet problem.?? Do I need to use google script.?? If so.. Do you have any code I can Use.??

Thanks

Comment: Not without seeing your spreadsheet and understanding exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What are you using GOOGLEFINANCE?

Comment: @TheWizEd google finance is limited with that. I'm trying to use google sheet functions

Comment: @Cooper I'm new here. I don't know yet how to share spreadsheet. I'm trying to add some financial data (ex: balance sheet) for every stock in my portofolio. For example, just saying I have 10 stocks. For the first stock (A1), I will need "B1:F25" cells for his data; the problem is that if I want add data of the second stock (A2), I could not do it because I already used B2:F25 cells for data of the first stock. I don't know if it is more clear of what I'm trying to do

Comment: I'm assuming you are using some sort of array function that fills in values below the formula?  You could use a script to put the formula in the cell, get the data, copy the data to another sheet, change the formula, put it in the cell again , get data for that symbol, copy it, etc. etc.  That's what I do with GOOGLEFINANCE.

Comment: That's 5 values in each row and 25 rows for a total of 125 parameters.  My guess that's a lot more than you currently know what to do with.  So I'd organize them with the most important to the left and flatten the array and put it all of one row for each stock.